# dynamic url for reactjs axios with a condition

Tags: reactjs

I have two ip adressess,let just assume them to be 32.64.25.22:3000 and 32.64.25.22:4000.
I want the axios to take diff url value as base according of the ip

so I have made a seperate file called baseUrl.js which has this code

```
export default {
    hostname = window.location.hostname; // gives ip adress
   
    URL1 = "32.64.25.22:3000",
    URL2 = "32.64.25.22:4000",
    if(hostname === URL1){
    apiUrl:' https://url1/api '
    }else if (hostname === URL2){
     apiUrl:' https://url2/api '
    }
```

this logic is not working and niether is

```
export default {
    hostname: window.location.hostname,
    URL1: "32.64.25.22:3000",

    apiUrl = (hostname === URL1) ? ' https://url1/api ' : 'https://url2/api ',
}
```

I am getting syntax errors..
Please send me a code with proper syntax, I am not sure why my visual studio code is not correcting syntax errors

this is the file in which i am importing my base url to

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import baseUrl from './components/baseUrl.js'
....
 axios
        .put(
          ` ${baseUrl.apiUrl}/eventName`
        )
...
```

Comment: after i do this, error goes away but another one shows saying hostname and url1 is not defined

Comment: after i replace : with = in both the host name and url, i got error in "apiUrl: (hostname === URL1) ? ' https://url1/api ' : 'https://url2/api "  saying  ..Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Comment: export default {
    hostname: window.location.hostname;
    URL1: "32.64.25.22:3000";

    apiUrl = (hostname === URL1) ? ' https://url1/api ' : 'https://url2/api ',
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the object incorrectly it should be like this

```
export default {
hostname :window.location.hostname,// gives ip adress

URL1 : "32.64.25.22:3000",
URL2 : "32.64.25.22:4000",
apiUrl:hostname===URL1?'https://url1/api':'https://url2/api'
```

}